# ctypes: get the actual address of a c function

Tags: python, cython, ctypes

This is tricky (at least to me :-) ,  maybe unfeasible. But I try to ask to you.

I have this c shared library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int variable = -666;

int get_value() {
    return variable;
}

void print_pointer_to_get_value() {
    printf("pointer_to_get_value: %p\n", &get_value);
}
```

Compiled this way (on Linux):

```
gcc -fPIC -c -O2 shared.c && gcc -shared -o shared.so shared.o
```

Now I load the library and call print_pointer_to_get_value():

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> so = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./shared.so')
>>> so.print_pointer_to_get_value()
pointer_to_get_value: 0x7f46e178f700
```

I'd like to get from ctypes the actual address, as integer, of the get_value function as printed by print_pointer_to_get_value(). 
My final target is to move that address to a Cython module and call that function inside a "nogil" Cython function. I need to load the .so library at runtime, therefore I cannot compile my Cython module linking it to the library.

Thanks 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nasty multistep process that isn't easy to do elegantly:

Some Cython code:

```
ctypedef double (*math_function_t)(double) nogil

import ctypes

def call_f(f, double x):
    cdef math_function_t cy_f_ptr = (<math_function_t*><size_t>ctypes.addressof(f))[0]

    cdef double res
    with nogil:
        res = cy_f_ptr(x)
    return res
```

Here I pass Cython a Ctypes function type (`f`) and get the address in Cython. I don't think it's possible to obtain the address in Python. As an example of how you might initialise `f`, on Linux you could do:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libm.so.6")
f = lib.sin

call_f(f,0.5) # returns sin(0.5)
```

(to use the standard library `sin` function).

The Cython line `cdef math_function_t cy_f_ptr = (<math_function_t*><size_t>ctypes.addressof(f))[0]` can be broken down as follows:

1. `ctypes.addressof(f)` gets the address that the `ctypes` variable `f` is held in. __This is NOT the value you're after_ - it's the place where the value you're after is stored.
2. This is cast first to a `size_t` integer then to a pointer to a `cdef` function pointer type. Cython requires the two step cast.
3. `[0]` dereferences your `math_function_t*` to get a `math_function_t`. This is the function pointer (i.e. the value you want)

---

The information for this answer was got from [this newsgroup thread](http://osdir.com/ml/python-cython-devel/2009-10/msg00202.html) (which I can't currently access)

Comment: That's sooooooooo perfect! You even told me why `ctypes.addressof()` gives a different pointer. One more question: why `<size_t>`? I'm not asking about the necessity of this cast but why size_t and not some other type.

Comment: It needs to be a big enough int to hold a pointer. Practically size_t does that (although it isn't guaranteed...). Although I think `uintptr_t` would actually have been the right thing to use